# Elasticsearch Facet Tokenization

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I am using [terms facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html) to get top `terms` in the elasticsearch server. Now my tags `"indian-government"` is not treated as one tag. Its treated as `"indian"` `"government"`. And so, the most used tag is `"indian"`. **How can I fix this? Should I change tokenization?**

```
        'settings': {
                'analysis': {
                        'analyzer': {
                                'my_ngram_analyzer' : {
                                        'tokenizer' : 'my_ngram_tokenizer',
                                         'filter': ['my_synonym_filter']
                                 }
                        },
                         'filter': {
                                 'my_synonym_filter': {
                                        'type': 'synonym',
                                        'format': 'wordnet',
                                        'synonyms_path': 'analysis/wn_s.pl'
                                }
                        },
                         'tokenizer' : {
                                 'my_ngram_tokenizer' : {
                                        'type' : 'nGram',
                                        'min_gram' : '1',
                                        'max_gram' : '50'
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
```

Edit: Based on comments, indexing as follows. The results do not change though:

```
    es.indices.create(
            index="article-index",
            body={
                    'settings': {
                            'analysis': {
                                    'analyzer': {
                                            'my_ngram_analyzer' : {
                                                    'tokenizer' : 'my_ngram_tokenizer',
                                                    'filter': ['my_synonym_filter']
                                            }
                                    },
                                    'filter': {
                                            'my_synonym_filter': {
                                                    'type': 'synonym',
                                                    'format': 'wordnet',
                                                    'synonyms_path': 'analysis/wn_s.pl'
                                            }
                                    },
                                    'tokenizer' : {
                                            'my_ngram_tokenizer' : {
                                                    'type' : 'nGram',
                                                    'min_gram' : '1',
                                                    'max_gram' : '50'
                                            }
                                    }
                            }
                    },
                       'mappings': {
                            'my_mapping_type': {
                                  '_all': {
                                    'enabled': False
                                  },
                                  '_source': {
                                    'compressed': True
                                  },
                                  'properties': {
                                    "tags": {
                                      "type": "string",
                                      "index": "not_analyzed"
                                    }
                                  }
                            }
                    }
            },
            # ignore already existing index
            ignore=400
    )
```

EDIT: Solved. my_mapping_type has to be replaced by doc_type (in my case, its 'article') and it works :)

Comment: I believe your tag field should be set to `not_analyzed`

Comment: Stupid question. Did you reindex? And which library are you using? What is the "ignore=400" for? You can check if the mapping did get updated using /_mapping.

Comment: Yes I re-indexed. I am using pyelasticsearch. Mapping did not get updated. Hence the question. Mapping is: {"article":{"properties":{"articleid":{"type":"long"},"domain":{"type":"string"},"tags":{"type":"string"},"text":{"type":"string"},"title":{"type":"string"},"url":{"type":"string"}}}}

Comment: How do you tell es to use mapping my_mapping_type for indexing? Looks like I have just defined a new mapping, but not used it for indexing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making field [`not_analysed`](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html) [should work](https://github.com/iPrayag/gccount/blob/master/gccount-front/scripts/customer_mapping.json#L7) if it fits your requirement.

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/INDEX -d '{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 5,
    "number_of_replicas": 2
  },
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "_all": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "_source": {
        "compressed": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "tag": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to re-index the docs I had indexed? Also, my field "tags" is really a list of strings. Sample "tags" is ["india", "indian-government"] ? How do I incorporate it? What should be the "type"?